# Number of arbiters in replication set

Tags: mongodb, replication, replicaset

In [MongoDB tutorial of deploying geographically distributed replica set](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-geographically-distributed-replica-set/) it is said that

> Ensure that a majority of the voting members are within a primary facility, “Site A”. This includes priority 0 members and **arbiters**.

I am confused by **arbiters** there since in other place [in documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-states/#states) I found that

> There should only be **at most one arbiter** configured **in any replica set**.

So how many arbiters at most can be in a replica set? If more that one arbiter allowed, then what is the point to have more than one arbiter in replica set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduction

The fact that "arbiters" is written in plural in the first sentence has style reasons, not technical reasons.

You really should have at most 1 arbiter. Iirc, you technically could have more, but to be honest with you, I never tried it. But let's assume you could for the sake of the explanation below.

You seem to be a bit unsure here, but correctly assume that it does not make any sense to have more than one arbiter.

## Recap: What are arbiters there for?

> An arbiter exists to provide a quorum in elections.

Take a replica set with two data bearing nodes. That setup will run as expected as long as both instances are up – they form a quorum of 2 votes of 2 original members of a replica set. If one machine goes down, however, we only have 1 vote of 2 originally present, which is not a qualified majority, and the data bearing node still running will subsequently revert to secondary state, making writes impossible.

To prevent that, an arbiter is added to the mix. An arbiter does nothing more than to track which of the available data bearing nodes has the most current data set available and vote for that member in case of an election. So with our replica set with two data bearing nodes, in order to get a qualified majority of votes in case 1 of the nodes forming the replica set goes down, we only need 1 arbiter, since 2/3 votes provides a qualified majority.

## Arbiters beyond 2 data bearing nodes

If we had a replica set with 3 data bearing nodes, we would not need an arbiter, since we have 3 voting members, and if 1 member goes down, the others still form a qualified majority needed to hold an election.

A bit more abstract, we can find out wether we need an arbiter by putting in the number of votes present in a replica set into the following "formula"

```
needArbiter = originalVotes - floor(originalVotes/2) <= originalVotes / 2
```

If we put in an additional arbiter, the number of votes would be 4: 3 data bearing nodes and 1 arbiter. One node goes down, no problem. Second node goes down, and the replica set will revert to secondary state. Now let's assume one of the two nodes down are is the arbiter – we would be in secondary state while the data bearing nodes only would be able to provide a quorum. We'd have to pay for and maintain an additional arbiter without anything gained from it. So in order to provide a qualified majority again, we would need to add yet another arbiter (making 2 now), without any benefit other than the fact that two arbiters can go down. You basically would need additional arbiters to prevent situations in which the existence of the arbiter you did not need in the first place becomes a problem.

Now let's assume we have 4 data bearing nodes. Since they can not form a qualified majority when 2 of them going down, that would pretty much be the same situation as with a replica set with 3 data bearing nodes, just more expensive. So in order to allow 2 nodes of the replica set being down at the same time, we simply add an arbiter. Do more arbiters make sense? No, even less than with a replica set with two or 3 data bearing nodes, since the probability that 2 data bearing nodes *and* the arbiter will fail at the same time is *very* low. And you'd need an uneven number of arbiters.

## Conclusion

Imho, with 4 data bearing nodes, the arbiter reaches its limit of usefulness. If you need a high replication factor the percentage of money saved when using an arbiter in comparison to a data bearing node becomes smaller and smaller. Remember, the next step would be 6 data bearing nodes plus an arbiter, so the costs you save is less than 1/6 of your overall costs.

So more generally speaking, the more data bearing nodes you have (the higher your "replication factor" in Mongo terms) the less reasonable it becomes to have additional arbiters. Both from the technical point of view (the probability of a majority of nodes failing the same time becomes lower and lower) and the business point of view (with a high replication factor, the money saved with an arbiter in comparison to the overall costs becomes absurdly small).

Mnemonic:

> The lowest uneven number is 1.

Comment: Ty for the answer. :) Say we have "set with 3 data bearing nodes". One member goes down (Primary). We have left with two secondary members. If they both vote for each other we have equal votes - 1 vote for one and 1 vote for other. They will not be able to elect a new primary?

Comment: @Spookiecookie Nope. The quorum is determined by the original members. 2 of 3 is enough.

Comment: For our special case it makes sense to have 2 arbiters. Let me explain: we have 3 data centers but 1 of these 3 data centers is not suitable to host data bearing members. That's why we host in this data center 2 arbiters for each replica set. The 3 data bearing members of the replSet are hosted in the two other data centers (we want to have 3 instead of 2 data bearing members for resilience reasons). If 1 of the 3 data center goes down or is not reachable due to a network partition, the replSet is still able to elect a primary, thus it's still read and writeable.

Comment: @Kay Maybe I am getting this wrong, but I fail to see the added benefit of having two data bearing nodes in one DC in this setup "for resilience reasons". If the connection of that DC fails, you do not have a quorum in this DC. You will have a quorum on the remaining data bearing node, but this could be achieved by having one data bearing node in each of the eligible Docs plus a single arbiter. While I see the potential performance gain having two data bearing nodes in one DC and a write concern of "majority", this does not make your setup any more resilient, as...

Comment: @Kay because if that DC fails, you have an acknowledged write for the data *which may still have not made it to the remaining data bearing node*. As per resilience, I'd rather go for two data bearing nodes per DC, a write concern of majority and a single arbiter.

Comment: @Markus, thank you for your input! Perhaps you got me wrong because I couldn't describe my case with the few characters allowed here. That's why I have created my own answer (see below please).So you say if one DC fails I don't have the quorum in the remaining DC. Why do should I need it? We don't use write concern majority, so the data is written and acknowledged by the remaining mongod which has been elected Primary with the help of the two arbiters. Having 2 mongod's in one DC adds resilience because 1 of them may die without any impact.

Answer (score 1):

I have a scenario where I think having more than 1 Arbiter makes sense.

**Problem**

I have 3 data bearing nodes in a replicaset. Now I want to distribute my replicaset geographically so that I can mitigate the risk of a datacenter outage.

**3 Node Replicaset, does not solve the problem**

- Primary Datacenter => 2 Data bearing Nodes
- Backup Datacenter => 1 Data bearing Node

If that primary datacenter is down and the two out of three nodes in the replicaset would not be available then data bearing node in backup datacenter would not be able to become a primary since majority is not available. So the 3 node configuration does not solve the problem of a datacenter outage.

**5 Node replicaset**

- Primary Datacenter => 2 Data bearing Nodes
- Backup Datacenter => 1 Data bearing Node
- Third Datacenter => 2 Arbiters

In this configuration I am able to sustain outage of any of the three datacenters and still be able to operate.

Obviously, a more ideal configuration would be to have 4 data bearing nodes and have 1 arbiter. It would give me redundancy in the backup datacenter as well. However since data bearing node is a much more expensive proposition than an arbiter going with 3 data bearing nodes and 2 arbiters makes more sense and I am happy to forgo the redundancy in backup datacenter in favor of the cost saving.

Comment: You're right, it may make sense to have 2 arbiters! We faced a similar problem where it makes sense to have 2 arbiters. I just added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For our special case it makes sense to have 2 arbiters. Let me explain: we have 3 data centers but 1 of these 3 data centers is not suitable to host data bearing members. That's why we host in this data center 2 arbiters for each replica set. The 3 data bearing members of the replSet are hosted in the two other data centers (we want to have 3 instead of 2 data bearing members for resilience reasons). If 1 of the 3 data center goes down or is not reachable due to a network partition, the replSet is still able to elect a primary, thus it's still read and writeable. This wouldn't be possible with only 1 or 0 arbiter. Hence, 2 arbiters may make sense.

Let's see how it may look like. Here are 2 replSets, each with 3 data bearing members and 2 arbiters in 3 data centers, whereas DC3 is the restricted data center:

```
|    |DC1  |DC2  |DC3  |
|----|-----|-----|-----|
|rs1 |m1,m2|m3   |a1,a2|
|rs2 |m1   |m2,m3|a1,a2|
```

If one data center goes down, which replSet member would become primary?

- DC1 goes down:

  - rs1: m3
  - rs2: m2 or m3
- DC2 goes down:

  - rs1: m1 or m2
  - rs2: m1
- DC3 goes down:

  - rs1: m1,m2 or m3